# Is it possible to use @Join annotation of Rewrite on JoinFaces?

Tags: joinfaces

I'd like to use @Join annotation in a joinFaces project. 
If it's possible, what the steps to configure and use it?

I'm using joinFaces 3.2.4 with rewrite-spring-boot-starter.

Comment: What @Join annotatoin do you mean?

Comment: https://github.com/ocpsoft/rewrite/blob/master/documentation/src/main/asciidoc/configuration/annotations/index.asciidoc#defining-rules-with-annotations

Answer (score -1):

Actually i found very very beautiful solution on this link By JSF itself

> page-redirect

hopefully be useful

https://www.codenotfound.com/jsf-welcome-page-redirect-example-spring-boot.html

I sent alot of time on it with no hope with Spring boot, But if you want
you need to add this dependencies

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ocpsoft.rewrite</groupId>
                <artifactId>rewrite-servlet</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.2.Final</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
                <groupId>org.ocpsoft.rewrite</groupId>
                <artifactId>rewrite-integration-faces</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.2.Final</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
               <groupId>org.ocpsoft.rewrite</groupId>
               <artifactId>rewrite-config-prettyfaces</artifactId>
               <version>3.4.2.Final</version>
      </dependency>
```